# Mathematica Table function to Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, loops, wolfram-mathematica

I need to convert this to Matlab code, and am struggling without the "table" function.

```
Table[{i,1000,ability,savingsrate,0,RandomInteger[{15,30}],1,0},{i,nrhhs}];
```

So basically, these values are all just numbers, and I think I need to use a function handle, or maybe a for loop. I'm no expert, so I really need some help?

Comment: Please consider that MATLAB users may not have Mathematica. Discribe your input data and what output you expecting. You can provide some screenshots.

Comment: Sorry. I was over tired when I left this comment yesterday. I don't really understand what the table function in Mathematica does - and I'm trying to convert code from Mathematica to Matlab. I think, it's simply creating a matrix with dimensions (6 x nrhhs). And then, using i, you can simulate the matrix to create a series of outputs over time.

Comment: this really cant be answered without knowing what ability and savingsrate are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Mathematics (just used it long time ago). According to this [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) for Table function, you are using this form:

> Table[expr, {i, imax}]
>
> generates a list of the values of expr when i runs from 1 to imax.

It looks like your statement will produce list duplicating the list in first argument increasing `i` from 1 to `nrhhs` and using different random number.

In MATLAB the output can be equivalent to a matrix or a cell array.

To create a matrix with rows as your lists you can do:

```
result = [ (1:nrhhs)', repmat([1000,ability,savingsrate,0],nrhhs,1), ...
           randi([15 30],nrhhs,1), repmat([1,0],nrhhs,1) ];
```

You can convert the above matrix to a cell array:

```
resultcell = cell2mat(result, ones(nrhhs,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Table" example you gave creates a list of nrhhs sub-lists, each of which contains 8 numbers (i, 1000, ability, savingsrate, 0, a random integer between 15 and 30 inclusive, 1, and 0).  This is essentially (though not exactly) the same as an nrhhs x 8 matrix.

Assuming you do just want a matrix out, though, an analogous for loop in Matlab would be:

```
result = zeros(nrhhs,8); % preallocate memory for the result
for i = 1:nrhhs
    result(i,:) = [i 1000 ability savingsrate 0 randi([15 30]) 1 0];
end
```

This method is likely slower than yuk's answer (which makes much more efficient use of vectors to avoid the for loop), but might be a little easier to pick apart depending on how familiar you are with Matlab.